# Angular modal- pass params from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have to put several params to the controller of the modal so I can display the value from some in[uts in the modal

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
   app.controller('ctrlTags', function($scope, $uibModal, $log){
//        $scope.items = tagsData;
       $scope.data = {
           repeatSelect: null,
           availableOptions: [
               {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
               {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
               {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
           ],
       };
        $scope.myVar = false;
        $scope.show = function () {
            $scope.myVar = false;
        }
        $scope.hide = function () {
            $scope.myVar = true;
        }
       $scope.open = function() {
           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
               templateUrl: 'myModl.html',
               controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
               resolve: {
                   param: function () {
                       $log.log($scope.dt)
                       return $scope.data;
                   }
               }
           });
       };
   $scope.ok = function() {
       $scope.showModal = false;
   };

   $scope.cancel = function() {
       $scope.showModal = false;
   };
});
```

The controller of the modal:

```
   app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, param) {

//        $scope.inputValue = param;
        $scope.data = param

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

I have to display more values except the data. How can I pass more params to the modal controller?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass more than one data in resovle function.

```
 $scope.open = function() {
           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
               templateUrl: 'myModl.html',
               controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
               resolve: {
                   param: function () {
                       $log.log($scope.dt)
                       return {'data':$scope.data,'yourData' : yourData };
                   }
               }
           });
       };


app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, param) {

//        $scope.inputValue = param.data;
        $scope.data = param.data;
        $scope.yourData = param.yourData;    
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

Comment: and in the html of the modal I just need to write {{data}}, {{yourdata}} for display the values?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `param` object before passing it from resolve for modal popup using `angular.extend`. In a effect you can inject only one `param` service inside popup controller & all the dependency would available in it.

```
resolve: {
    param: function () {
        var param = {};
        angular.extend(param, $scope.dt);
        angular.extend(param, someOtherData1);
        angular.extend(param, someOtherData2);
        $log.log(param); //will show you combine data
        return param;
    }
}
```